# trying to solve the golf slang homework about the slang that golfer use

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

so i have a homework that is due soon and i did my best and i know i have couple mistakes but i couldnt figure how to solve it.

You will write a program which will take input from the user for three things:

the hole number,
the par value for a hole and
the number of strokes the golfer took to complete the hole.

You will then generate the appropriate golfer slang for the hole using the table below:

Golfer strokes in relationship to par:

```
-5, "Ostrich"

-4, "Condor"

-3, "Albatross"

-2, "Eagle"

-1, "Birdie"

0, "Even Par" or "Even" or "Par"

+1, "Bogey"

+2, "Double Bogey"

+3, "Triple Bogey"

+4, "4 over par"

+5, "5 over par", etc.
```

A person who has shot twice the value of par has:

```
X2, (double the par), "Beagle"
```

Golfer actual number of strokes:

```
1, "Hole in One" or "Ace"

4, "Sailboat"

8, "Snowman", "Frosty" or "Dog Balls"

10, "Bo Derek"
```

then it should display like this

> > >
> >     Enter the hole number:1
> >     Enter the par for the hole:4
> >     Enter the number of strokes:4
> >     On hole # 1 a par 4 you shot a Even Par, with a Sailboat.
> >     >

and my program is like this one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GolfSlang {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numbers = 0;
    int parhole = 0;
    int strokes = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter the hole number: ");
    double number = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("the par value for a hole: ");
    double par = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("The number of strokes the golfer took to complete the hole:");
    double stroke = input.nextDouble();

    if (par == -5) {
        System.out.println(" Ostrich ");
    } else if (par == -4) {
        System.out.println("Condor");
    } else if (par == -3) {
        System.out.println("Albatross");
    } else if (par == -2) {
        System.out.println("Eagle");
    } else if (par == -1) {
        System.out.println("Birdie");
    } else if (par == 0)  {
        System.out.println("Even Par");
    } else if (par == 1) {
        System.out.println("Bogey");
    } else if (par == 2) {
        System.out.println("Double Bogey");
    } else if (par == 3) {
        System.out.println("Triple Bogey");
    } else if (par == 4) {
        System.out.println("4 over par");
    } else if (par == 5) {
        System.out.println("5 over par");
    } else {

    }

    if ((stroke /2)== par) {
        System.out.println("Beagle");
    } else if (stroke == 1) {
        System.out.println("Ace");
    } else if (stroke == 4) {
        System.out.println("Sailboat");
    } else if (stroke == 8) {
        System.out.println("Snowman");
    } else if (stroke == 10) {
        System.out.println("Bo Derek");
    }

    } else {
        System.out.println("On hole # " + numbers + " a par " + par + "you shot" + stroke); {
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question, though?

Comment: So what is your question? For which input doesn't your program work as expected? Any error messages?

Comment: nothing really showed and the message i got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at GolfSlang.main(GolfSlang.java:5)

Comment: Count your left and right parenthesis in if-else statement (21/20).

Comment: Not sure I'm reading this right, but you have statements saying if `par`, being the par for the hole, is a certain value for the statements. It should be a difference between strokes and par that gives a negative value. Otherwise, you always get a "Triple Bogey" on a par 3 hole and "Bogey" on par 1 holes, etc. Should be `if (stroke-par == -5)…`

Answer (score 0):

first if(){} else(){} section is useless for what you want. you keep the stored par value and the stroke value. you need to check the difference of stroke to par {int val = stoke - par;}. first section of comparisons should be with val instead of par. (recommend switch-case since it's just a long list of basic comparisons). since you want to print everything out at the end, you should save the strings instead of using println(initialize before comparisons). you can use printf("whatever %s", string) to integrate more simply for the print

Comment: the compilation error is likely due to the incorrect bracketing. last else statement is is stated as              else{block{}}          this just closes your else statement, but not your main method and class